# TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_validation_error'"

Tags: jupyter-lab

I updated jupyter and conda, then after opening jupyter lab, when I tried to open a notebook, I got an error of below. The file was working fine without any error before.

```
Unreadable Notebook: U:\Data\test.ipynb TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_validation_error'")
```

the same file can be opened in other pc with old enviroment. not sure what is the problem?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using `python3.9`. I use a conda environment to handle the versioning.

Create an environment with `python3.9`

```
conda create -n myenvpython39 python=3.9
```

Activate the environment

```
conda activate myenvpython39
```

Install jupyterlab within myenvpython39

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

Comment: just running 'conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab' solved my problem.